# Buscar Cep em um outro banco no Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cep

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro usando o Laravel 5, criei o esquema cliente, com algumas tabelas, como pessoa, endereco, e-mail, telefone.
acontece tenho um outro banco, chamado cep, onde tem algumas tabelas como rua,  us, bairro, cidade.
Eu sou bem iniciante nesse framework, tudo o que consegui fazer foi imitando outros modelos prontos.
O Cadastro está funcionando, tanto a busca no banco, como a inclusão.
Minha dúvida, como faço para digitar o cep em um html e através desse cep o input no form preencher os campos de rua, cidade, bairro, estado?
Obrigado.

Obs. eu fiz esse select no mysql, deu certo, agora nao sei como implementar no laravel

```
USE cep;
        SELECT e.endereco_logradouro, b.bairro_descricao, c.cidade_descricao, u.uf_sigla, u.uf_descricao
        FROM endereco e, bairro b, cidade c, uf u
        WHERE e.bairro_codigo = b.bairro_codigo AND
        b.cidade_codigo = c.cidade_codigo AND
        c.uf_codigo = u.uf_codigo AND e.endereco_cep = 'variável'
```

Comment: É melhor você configurar o banco de dados na sua aplicação e usá-lo em um model específico do  `Laravel`. Ele já tem a sua própria abstração, e isso vai economizar trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar mais de um banco de dados no `Laravel`.

Exemplo:

```
    'mysql' => array(
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'srvweb',
        'password'  => '...',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => ''
    ),

   'mysql_2' => array(
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host',
        'database'  => 'database_2',
        'username'  => 'srvweb',
        'password'  => '...',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => ''
    ),
```

Observe que sempre você tem várias configurações no `Laravel`, para mais de um tipo de SGDB. Não há problemas em configurar mais de um banco para o mesmo SGDB.

Você também deve percebido outro parâmetro chamado `default` que você deve configurar:

```
  'default' => 'mysql',
```

Esse é o banco padrão usado em todos os seus Models.

A minha sugestão é você configurar outro banco e, no model referente ao `Cep`, você vai definir que ele usará a conexão com outro banco de dados.

```
    class Cep extends \Eloquent
    {
          protected $connection = 'mysql_2';

          // Outras definições
    }
```

Daí por diante, basta fazer as consultas com esse `Model`:

```
   $ceps = Cep::where('endereco', 'LIKE', 'valor%')->get();
```

É apenas uma "configurações ilustrativa". Você pode usar a sua criatividade para organizar melhor o seu projeto (e o seu tempo).